# How can I make my stripey texture "curve" downwards with the curve of my object? Unsolved

Tags: texturing

I'm using a mapping node to cause a noise texture to compress along the Z axis, making horizontal stripes. I'd like to have those stripes curve down the object from the "hip" joint on the right, to the foot on the left, instead of staying perfectly horizontal. Is there a way to set this up?

[image: Legtexture]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Texture Coordinate* UV output: Select all in *Edit* mode, shift select one orthogonal face, press <kbd>U</kbd> *(Unwrap) > Follow Active Quads*:

[image]

It will create an orthogonal UV, which will make the texture follow the shape:

[image]